# How can I map an SQL Server geometry column to an EF6 property

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, nettopologysuite

I have a nullable geography column in a table in a SQL Server database. In an Azure Function project (v4, .NET 6.08, NetTopologySuite included), when using `Scaffold-DbContext` to create an EF6 data context, the geometry column was mapped to `Geometry?` which seems right.

But when I run the project, and initialize the `DBContext`, I get the following error:

> The property 'Geometry.UserData' could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type.

BTW, I tried to change `Geometry?` to `Point?` but this made no difference.

What is going on? How can I map a `Geography` column to an EF6 property?

Comment: Have you added "UseNetTopllogySuite" ?

Comment: I was not using it. Adding it to UseSqlServer did indeed do the trick, Thanks! If you want to add an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must configure the SQL Server provider options by enabling support for spatial type mappings with "UseNetTopologySuite":

```
options.UseSqlServer(
    @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=WideWorldImporters",
        x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
```